# Why does my Discord bot does not open or store things in the JSON file correctly?

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I am currently creating a reaction role event. There you can set a reaction role via command. The format is: `>reactionss @role messageID emote`. The bot then will add the reaction to the given message.
(You react with the given emote on the message and get the role. Unreacting will remove it.)
Therefore I stored everything in a JSON file. The format can be seen in the code. It works perfectly fine. After restarting the bot everything seems to be unstored/nothing happens when I click on the reaction. However everything seems to be still stored in the JSON file but it is not used.
My code so far:

````
class ReactionRoles(commands.Cog):
    """
    This instance handles all reaction role events.
    """

    def __init__(self, bot):
        super().__init__()
        self.bot = bot
        self.reaction_roles = []

    @commands.command(name="Reaction", aliases=["reactionss"])
    async def set_reaction(self, ctx, role: discord.Role = None, msg: discord.Message = None, emoji=None):
        with open('reaction_roles.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            reaction_roles = json.load(f)

        try:
            reaction_roles[f"{role.id}, {msg.id}"] = emoji
        except KeyError:
            new = {ctx.message.id: role.id}
            reaction_roles.update(new)

        if role is not None and msg is not None and emoji is not None:
            await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
            self.reaction_roles.append((role.id, msg.id, str(emoji.encode("utf-8"))))

            with open('reaction_roles.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                json.dump(reaction_roles, f, indent=2)

            await ctx.channel.send("**Reaction has been set.**")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        for role_id, msg_id, emoji in self.reaction_roles:
            if msg_id == payload.message_id and emoji == str(payload.emoji.name.encode("utf-8")):
                await payload.member.add_roles(self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id).get_role(role_id))

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        for role_id, msg_id, emoji in self.reaction_roles:
            if msg_id == payload.message_id and emoji == str(payload.emoji.name.encode("utf-8")):
                guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
                await guild.get_member(payload.user_id).remove_roles(guild.get_role(role_id))```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work after resetting is because every time it does reset, it redefines the `reaction_roles` list and sets it to empty.

```py
    def __init__(self, bot):
        super().__init__()
        self.bot = bot
        self.reaction_roles = [] # Whenever code reloads, this is set here, and is empty
```

Your `on_raw_reaction_add` and `on_raw_reaction_remove` are using this list to determine reactions and roles, not the JSON file.

You can do something like this, using dicts and only the JSON file. JSON doesn't support integers as keys, so any time working with msg.id, use str(msg.id)

```py
# Not really necessary, but we need to read the file multiple times
# If you ever relocate it, you will only need to edit it once
def json_open(): #you can rename it, just remember to change the rest as well
    with open('reaction_roles.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        reaction_roles = json.load(f)
        return reaction_roles


class Reactions(commands.Cog):
    """
    This instance handles all reaction role events.
    """
    def __init__(self, bot):
        super().__init__()
        self.bot = bot


    @commands.command(name="Reaction", aliases=["reactionss"])
    async def set_reaction(self, ctx, role: discord.Role = None, msg: discord.Message = None, emoji=None):
        reaction_roles = json_open() # Open the json file

        # First time registering emoji to msg will give error since msg is not in dict
        try:
            role_dict = reaction_roles[str(msg.id)]
        except:
            role_dict = {}

        role_dict[emoji] = role.id
        reaction_roles[str(msg.id)]=role_dict

        if role is not None and msg is not None and emoji is not None:
            await msg.add_reaction(emoji)

            with open('reaction_roles.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                json.dump(reaction_roles, f, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
                # setting ensure_ascii=False --> We can have actual emojis in json
                
            await ctx.channel.send("**Reaction has been set.**")

    # Next two steps are same, except one is remove and one is add
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        if payload.user_id == 775390992777216040: # Bot wont accidentally get any roles
            return
        reaction_roles = json_open() # Open JSON
        if str(payload.message_id) in list(reaction_roles.keys()): # If msg matches
            role_dict = reaction_roles[str(payload.message_id)]    # If reaction matches
            if payload.emoji.name in list(role_dict.keys()):
                role_id = role_dict[payload.emoji.name]
                guild = self.client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
                role = guild.get_role(role_id)
                await guild.get_member(payload.user_id).add_roles(role)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        if payload.user_id == 775390992777216040:
            return
        reaction_roles = json_open()
        if str(payload.message_id) in list(reaction_roles.keys()):
            role_dict = reaction_roles[str(payload.message_id)]
            if payload.emoji.name in list(role_dict.keys()):
                role_id = role_dict[payload.emoji.name]
                guild = self.client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
                role = guild.get_role(role_id)
                await guild.get_member(payload.user_id).remove_roles(role)
```

The JSON file will end up looking like this

```json
{
  "msg1_id": {
    "": role1_id,
    "": role2_id
  },
  "msg2_id": {
    "": role3_id
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what do we have to do for "json_open" as I am working with commands? Do I just set it the following: `reaction_roles= self.bot.json_open()`?

Comment: @Dominik you don't have to do anything with it. The reason I put it there is that when we need to open the `reaction_roles.json` file (we open it three times just in this bit of code)  we can do `reaction_roles = json_open()`. Since `json_open()` is a function, every time it's called, it will open the json file and return `reaction_roles` which we can work with. I define it before the class, at the very top of the code. Now if you change the file name or location, you only need to edit it at the top once, instead of three times in the code